# Warning messages using java azure client

Tags: java, azure

Using azure-storage-blob-client, I see these:

```
10:46:38 [main] WARN  JacksonVersion - Could not find version of 'jackson-annotations'. 
10:46:38 [main] ERROR JacksonVersion - Version 'unknown' of package 'jackson-annotations' is not supported (older than earliest supported version - `2.10.0`), please upgrade. 
10:46:38 [main] WARN  JacksonVersion - Could not find version of 'jackson-core'. 
10:46:38 [main] ERROR JacksonVersion - Version 'unknown' of package 'jackson-core' is not supported (older than earliest supported version - `2.10.0`), please upgrade. 
10:46:38 [main] WARN  JacksonVersion - Could not find version of 'jackson-databind'. 
10:46:38 [main] ERROR JacksonVersion - Version 'unknown' of package 'jackson-databind' is not supported (older than earliest supported version - `2.10.0`), please upgrade. 
10:46:38 [main] INFO  JacksonVersion - Package versions: jackson-annotations=unknown, jackson-core=unknown, jackson-databind=unknown, jackson-dataformat-xml=2.12.5, jackson-datatype-jsr310=2.12.5, azure-core=1.21.0 
10:46:38 [main] DEBUG MemberNameConverterImpl - Failed to retrieve MethodHandles used to get naming strategy. Falling back to BeanUtils. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AccessorNamingStrategy.Provider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.jackson.MemberNameConverterImpl.<clinit>(MemberNameConverterImpl.java:55)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.jackson.ObjectMapperShim.<init>(ObjectMapperShim.java:139)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.jackson.ObjectMapperShim.createHeaderMapper(ObjectMapperShim.java:127)
    at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.<init>(JacksonAdapter.java:75)
    at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.<init>(JacksonAdapter.java:53)
    at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.createDefaultSerializerAdapter(JacksonAdapter.java:111)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.implementation.util.ModelHelper.<clinit>(ModelHelper.java:53)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobUrlParts.parse(BlobUrlParts.java:371)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder.endpoint(BlobServiceClientBuilder.java:147)
    at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder.connectionString(BlobServiceClientBuilder.java:286)
```

Why do I get these warning messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out one of my dependencies was a "shaded jar" including the jackson components.  This shading processes apparently stripped from the jar some kind of version info of which version of jackson was defined.  It could safely be ignored.